# How to extract age and gender from reddit post titles?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, reddit

I am trying to scrape Reddit posts of subreddits where a lot of questions are in the form:

`s1 = "I [22M] and my partner (21F) are foo and bar"`

`s2 = "My (22m) and my partner (21m) are bar and foo"`

I want to make a function that can parse each string and then return age and gender pairs. So:

```
def parse(s1):
 ....
 return [(22, "male"), (21, "female")]
```

Essentially, each age/gender tag is a two-digit number followed by either `f, F, m, M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to extract the matches using this Regex:

```
(?:[\[\(])(\d{1,2})([MF])(?:[\]\)]) /i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f6W5na/7)

For the python part of things I would recommend `re`'s [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method:

```
import re

def parse(title):
    return re.findall(r'(?:\[|\()(\d{1,2})([MF])(?:\]|\))', title, re.IGNORECASE)

title = 'I [22M] and my partner (21F) are foo and bar'
matches = parse(title)

print(matches)
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ3Ht4LgS)

**EDIT:**

You could try to modify your Regex to this, in order to fit the new requirement you mentioned in your comment:

```
(?:[\[\(])(\d{1,2})\s?([MF]|male|female)(?:[\]\)]) /i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f6W5na/8)

Comment: Hi, I know this is out of scope of the original question but I had a follow-up. suppose that another option for this stuff is like "22 Male" or "23 female".  How would I account for the gender tag being preceded by a space?

Comment: @jdoe Try matching `(\d+)\s*(male|female)` with `re.findall`, in case insensitive mode.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.findall` here:

```
s1 = "I [22m] and my partner (21F) are foo and bar"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:[\[(](\d+[MF])[\])])', s1, re.IGNORECASE)
print(matches)

[('22', 'm'), ('21', 'F')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex with `re` :

```py
import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\[|\()[^\)\]]+', s1)  # find text within () or []
['22M', '21F']
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', '22M') # find age
['22']
>>> re.findall(r'[fFmM]+', '22M') # find gender
['M']
```

This website is really nice to learn and practice on Regex: https://regex101.com/